# How to apply expect over softAssertAll or show explicity in the test result that the softAssertAll passed (Error: Expected Object to be a function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mocha.js, cypress

I'm using 'soft-assert' library ([soft-assert library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soft-assert)) to apply assertion on my test steps without stopping the test if any of them fail.

According to the documentation, all soft-assert is verified at the end of the test by using softAssertAll() command. And this works very well. However, if nothing fails, I don't see any explicit message in my test result as when I use expect command.

So, I'm trying to apply expect over the softAssertAll() command, as it's seen below, but I'm getting the error message:
**"expected { Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) } to be a function"**

What I'm trying to do:

```
 expect(cy.softAssertAll()).not.throw(Error)
```

Does anyone know how can I do this or solve the error in the image below?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The docs say `Using softAssert, softContains, softAssertKey, softTrue, softAssertKeyAbsence asserts the value but does not throws the AssertionError, until softAssertAll is called.

softAssertAll - throws the error of all the previous soft assertion's error if any`, are you using any of those?

Comment: Yes. Before calling softAssertAll I'm using softAssert many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Chai example for [throw](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw)

```js
var badFn = function () { throw new TypeError('Illegal salmon!'); };
expect(badFn).to.throw();
```

Note you pass in the ***function name*** without invoking it. I think this allows chai to wrap the function invocation in a try-catch and gracefully report the failure.

You can't do the same with a Cypress custom command as it will not raise errors in the same way as `badFn` above. Internally it swallows any error and sets the state of the test to "failed".

You could reasonably expect this to work

```js
expect(jsonAssertion.softAssertAll).not.throw()
```

however there's an internal error in `jsonAssertion` that seems to be related to the `this` reference inside it's class.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_softThrowJsonDiffArray')

To fix, use an arrow function

```js
const testSoftAssertAll = () => jsonAssertion.softAssertAll();
expect(testSoftAssertAll).not.throw()
```

or shorter

```js
expect(() => jsonAssertion.softAssertAll()).not.throw()
```

---

#### Check the diff array

This is cleaner and clearer

```js
// expect all soft-assert to be passing
expect(jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray).to.eq(undefined)

// expect first soft-assert to fail with a certain message
expect(jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray[0].error.message).to.contain('Illegal salmon')
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end, what worked best for me was adding the line:
    expect(() => jsonAssertion.softAssertAll()).not.throw()
just below jsonAssertion.softAssertAll() within my softAssertAll custom Commands

because this line: 
    expect(jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray).to.have.length(0)
throws the error: Target cannot be null or undefined
and this one:
    expect(jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray[0].error.message).to.contain('Illegal salmon')
throws the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: The line `jsonAssertion.softAssertAll()` clears all the diffs, so calling `expect(() => jsonAssertion.softAssertAll).not.throw()` after it will always pass. It's a faulty test.

Comment: But `expect(jsonAssertion.jsonDiffArray).to.have.length(0)` is also no good if all soft-asserts pass because the array is undefined initially. Can use `satisfy` to avoid that problem.